# Angular 4 ngIf inside ngFor not functioning as expected

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

The issue that I am having is that I am not getting the expected functionality out of my *ngIf statement inside an *ngFor. I am using it to iterate through custom validation messages and each ngIf has a unique statement. The following is the component.html file I am working with:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="{{title}}">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{title}}" name="{{title}}" [(ngModel)]="vm.title" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" #title="ngModel" minlength="{{minLength}}" maxlength="{{maxLength}}" required />
<div *ngIf="title.errors && (title.dirty || title.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngFor="let validation of validations">
        <div *ngIf="validation.method">{{validation.message}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the component.ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'textbox',
    templateUrl: './textbox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./textbox.component.css']
})

export class TextboxComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('title') title: string;
    @Input('required') required: boolean;
    @Input('required-message') requiredMessage: string;
    @Input('min-length') minLength: number;
    @Input('min-length-message') minLengthMessage: string;
    @Input('max-length') maxLength: number;
    @Input('max-length-message') maxLengthMessage: string;
    validations: Validation[] = [];

    public vm: SignUp;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.vm = new SignUp();
        if (this.required) {
            if (this.requiredMessage[0] != "") {
                this.validations.push(new Validation(this.title + ".errors.required", this.requiredMessage));
            } else {
                this.validations.push(new Validation("!" + this.title + ".errors.required", "First name is required"));
            }
        } else {
            //make not required
        }
        if (this.minLength) {
            if (this.minLengthMessage) {
                this.validations.push(new Validation(this.title + ".errors.minlength", this.minLengthMessage));
            } else {
                this.validations.push(new Validation("!" + this.title + ".errors.minlength", "Minimun length is " + this.minLength));
            }
        }
        if (this.maxLength) {
            if (this.maxLengthMessage) {
                this.validations.push(new Validation(this.title + ".errors.maxlength", this.maxLengthMessage));
            } else {
                this.validations.push(new Validation("!" + this.title + ".errors.maxlength", "Maximun length is " + this.maxLength));
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i > this.validations.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.validations[i].method);
            console.log(this.validations[i].message);
        }
    }
}
export class SignUp {
    nameFirst: string;
    nameLast: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
export class Validation {
    constructor(public method: string, public message: string) {
        console.log(method);
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

I am calling the component from another component like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <form #form="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textbox [title]="'nameFirst'" [required]="true" [required-message]="'required message test'" [min-length]="5" [min-length-message]="'minimum length test'" [max-length]="10" [max-length-message]="'maximum length test'"></textbox>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

What ends up happening is that all the validation messages display regardless of whether they should be triggered. For example, "max length test" is showing even though I'm no where near the max # of characters.

Here is a plunkr to play around with the functionality:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IgQ9WxSHVaTz7zz0aajU

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="validation.method">{{validation.message}}</div>
```

You're having the message show as long as `validation.method` exists. Every time you create a `Validation`, you're doing it like this:

`new Validation(this.title + ".errors.minlength", this.minLengthMessage)`

The Validation's `method` property is a `string` and is never empty, so the `*ngIf` directive is always evaluating to true.

Answer (score 0):

What Jun Kang said. Also, it seems like you are doing an awful lot of work that you don't need to be. Have you looked into building Reactive Forms? Here's a short example:

```
  createForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      street: ['', [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

Then you'd simply use an ngIf for each validator in your HTML. Walk through Angular's example. It's useful and your code will be easier to handle: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I was going to mention this as well, but I thought it wasn't necessary to the original question. But yea, he's doing work that he doesn't need to. He could even just use a template driven form. Since the `Validation`'s he's using are just `required`, `min-length` and `max-length`, which are validators already built into Angular's template driven forms.

Comment: Exactly right. It just seemed like he was doing all this extra work he didn't need to be doing. Either template driven or reactive forms approach will work for this use case.

Comment: I have looked into reactive forms a bit and it seems like using one would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do here as far as I can tell. What I am going for are individual form inputs that are modular and can be called from anywhere and customized from where they are called. What I don't want is an entire form since I may need inputs and selectors and radials in one place and just a couple inputs in another. I also may need inputs that may or may not be required (defined by the caller).